# gcc --whole-archive --no-whole-archive: Dynamic Library Integrity

Tags: linux, gcc, ld

When using the `-Wl--whole-archive ... -Wl--no-whole-archive` flags with gcc how is it that you veryify that everything links correctlly internal to the library? Also how do you verify that the library can call into other Dynamic libries that are specifed by LD_LIBRARY_PATH or ld(1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to build a shared library one solution would be to link a minimal executable against that library as part of you build and see if you get unresolved symbols. Of course this file wouldn't be installed.

The executable you build can really be minimal, for my C++ code I usually use

```
int main() { }
```

Comment: Thanks, "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime." Greatly appreciated.